# Google Chrome Native Messaging Example returns: Uncaught TypeError: chrome.runtime.connectNative is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get Google's Native Messaging example code to run out of the box.
I've downloaded it from here:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#examples

I've registered the host.
I've installed the extension.
I've verified the ID's match.
But when I load the "main.html" page & hit the "Connect" button I get:
"Uncaught TypeError: chrome.runtime.connectNative is not a function"

I'm on Win. 7 x64, Chrome Version 45.0.2454.85 m

Any suggestions on what's wrong?

Comment: This example app runs here on win7x64, Chrome 46. I only had to force python2 as both v2 and v3 are installed (`py -2` instead of `python` in `native-messaging-example-host.bat`). Make sure you don't open the html directly but launch the app from chrome's app launcher or chrome://apps/.

Comment: Oh thanks so much for the reply. My issues was I was opening the html file directly. I changed the `native-messaging-example-host.bat` to just launch calc.exe, since I don't have python installed & that worked. But how do I set up the extension to run off of any html file instead of having to go through the app launcher?

Comment: That seems to be another question, but since the original one was caused by misunderstanding of what an app is in Chrome, maybe it's worth changing the question and explain in detail the new goal and whatever issues you're having with it.

Comment: OK I post a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384892/getting-sterted-with-google-chrome-native-messaging