# Getting started with Google Chrome Native Messaging

Tags: google-chrome

We previously developed a [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) plug-in that we use for our in-house intranet site. It preforms some very basic tasks like launch Windows Explore in a given project folder, launch Word or LibreOffice with the correct template & fill in contact information, etc.

As I'm sure most of you know NPAPI plug-ins are no longer supported in Chrome, so we're now having to port these custom functions to a Native Messaging app. I was able to get the [example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#examples) app to launch Calc.exe from the Google App Launcher page.

So my question is how can I create a link/button in any html page that will run my host app to launch calc.exe without having to go through the App launcher?

Comment: You don't have to make a Chrome app as the extensions can also communicate with native hosts. That was probably already covered on stackoverflow. Use the standard method: inject a content script which displays the button which will send a message to the event/background page which will communicate with the native host app.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, but I'm new to all this. I don't know what the standard method is. Could you give me an example of how to inject a content script?

Comment: Why, of course start with the official [extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview), it has all the info with links to the more detailed references and the sample extensions are there. And there are lots of solutions on stackoverflow. Currently your question appears too broad or lacking the research effort, whereas it should be about specific problems with the code you have.