# chrome.runtime.connectNative is undefined

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I'm building a chrome extension which should connect to a console application.

This is my manifest file:

```
{
  "name": "my extension",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "my extension",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "src/inject/inject.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have this line in inject.js:

```
chrome.runtime.connectNative("org.my_company.my_application");
```

which throws a type error because connectNative is undefined, how could it be undefined when I have the permission for native messaging ? what should I do to solve the problem ?

By the way I've seen this question: [Google Chrome Native Messaging Example returns: Uncaught TypeError: chrome.runtime.connectNative is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32365065/google-chrome-native-messaging-example-returns-uncaught-typeerror-chrome-runti) but the question is for chrome app and I'm building an extension.

my chrome version is 64 on windows 7 x64.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm using it in a content script

Answer (score 5):

It turned out that native messaging isn't allowed in content scripts and should be done in a background page.

Comment: i placed `chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage` inside my service worker background.js but i got `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Native host has exited.`. any advice?